# clustering on the base of k means centroid

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have images of 1500 patients's lungs, And I am trying to apply kmean on them to solve my issue. My problem is, I want to apply k mean on one patient (has 230 images )  then saving the centroid of this patient, i want to apply kmeans on other patients based on this centroid. This is the matlab code.
    `[idx,C] = kmeans(data,80)`
Now,  I have `C` but what should I do to use it and apply this centroid on the other images as well?

Here' what my data looks like, I am clustering based upon the histograms of these images.

```
Img1   histogram with 16 bins
Img2   Histo gram with 16 bins
Img3   // // // // // // //
Img4   // / / / // /// // / 
 .
 .
 .
```

Any tutorial or anything that might help, please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in [Kmeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) the membership of each point determined by the *closest center*. Therefore, after you have the centers you can keep associating more points by checking their distance from each center. in matlab you can easily do it with `pdist2`:

```
dim = 2;
n = 100;
% generate two data sets
data1 = rand(n,dim);
data2 = rand(n,dim);
% computing membership & clusters using kmeans on data1
k = 5;
[idx1,C] = kmeans(data1,k);
% computing membership using pairwise distance on data2
D = pdist2(data2,C);
[~,idx2] = min(D,[],2);
% plot centers
scatter(C(:,1),C(:,2),100,1:k,'*')
hold on
% plot data1
scatter(data1(:,1),data1(:,2),30,idx1,'filled')
% plot data2
scatter(data2(:,1),data2(:,2),30,idx2)
legend('centers','data1','data2')
```

if you want you can even plot the membership limits using Voronoi diagram:

```
voronoi(C(:,1),C(:,2));
```

[image]